# Collapse content instead of scrolling when CollapsingToolbarLayout is expanded

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've created a simple project with Android's `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, this is its structure (full layout source on the bottom of the question):

```
CoordinatorLayout
  AppBarLayout
    CollapsingToolbarLayout
      Toolbar
  RelativeLayout (layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior")
    TextView (layout_alignParentTop="true")
    TextView (layout_alignParentBottom="true")
```

When I'm expanding/collapsing the bar, the view is scrolled and bottom view goes beyond the screen:
[image]

What I'm going to achieve is collapsing/shrinking (instead of scrolling) the content (my `RelativeLayout`) in the way that bottom text always stays visible:

[image]
[image]

How can I do it on the Android?

This is my full layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="The text on the top"
            android:textSize="32sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="The text on the bottom"
            android:textSize="32sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: im looking for something really similar. cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real issue here is how to get the `RelativeLayout` sized properly when the app bar changes height. Before looking at how to do that, we need to make changes to the XML layout.

From the [documentation for AppBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html):

> AppBarLayout also requires a separate scrolling sibling in order to know when to scroll.

Since the RelativeLayout` does not qualify as a "scrolling sibling," we need to encase it in one such as "NestedScrollView." Here is the updated XML file:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayoutProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="The text on the top"
                android:textSize="32sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="The text on the bottom"
                android:textSize="32sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I may have made a few other changes to the XML to make things work in my environment, but there should be no substantive changes other than inserting `NestedScrollView`.

Changes to the size of the the `RelativeLayout` will be set in code and will be triggered by an [AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener.html). We will compute and change the size of the `RelativeLayout` based on the vertical offset of the app bar.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        final AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appBar);
        final int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        appBarLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adjustRelLayoutHeight(mRelativeLayout, screenHeight - appBarLayout.getBottom());
            }
        });

        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                adjustRelLayoutHeight(mRelativeLayout, screenHeight - appBarLayout.getBottom());
            }
        });
    }

    private void adjustRelLayoutHeight(RelativeLayout layout, int newHeight) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = newHeight;
        layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

**Update:** The following is an alternate approach that uses `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener()` that avoids an extra draw. The effect is the same however:

**MainActivity.java (alternate method)**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    private int mCoordinatorHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        final AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appBar);

        final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout =
            (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayoutProfile);
        // Wait for just before drawing the view to get its height.
        coordinatorLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    // Remove the listener so we don't go into an infinite loop.
                    coordinatorLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    mCoordinatorHeight = coordinatorLayout.getHeight();
                    adjustRelLayoutHeight(mRelativeLayout, mCoordinatorHeight - appBarLayout.getBottom());
                    return false; // abort drawing
                }
            });

        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                adjustRelLayoutHeight(mRelativeLayout, mCoordinatorHeight - appBarLayout.getBottom());
            }
        });
    }

    private void adjustRelLayoutHeight(RelativeLayout layout, int newHeight) {
        if (newHeight <= 0) {
            // no-op if height is invalid
            return;
        }
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
        if (lp.height != newHeight) {
            lp.height = newHeight;
            layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using RelativeLayout with layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" you should choose either NestedScrollingView or RecyclerViw to get everything works as expected.

As it’s stated [here](https://material.io/components/android/catalog/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

> The scrolling content should be placed in a RecyclerView,
>   NestedScrollView, or another view that supports nested scrolling.

Considering your layout I guess you need to place your RelativeLayout inside NestedScrollingView and assign layout_behavior to NestedScrollingView and remove layout_behavior from RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height= "match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="The text on the top"
                android:textSize="32sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="The text on the bottom"
                android:textSize="32sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**EDIT 11/4/2017 4:58PM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="The text on the top"
                    android:textSize="32sp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="The text on the bottom"
        android:textSize="32sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now it works as it's shown below

[image: Result View]

Comment: I have tried your solution, but in the result, both texts are in the same place (overlaping each other) - the `RelativeLayout` does not fill whole space under the `ActionBar`, instead just wraps the texts.

Comment: Thanks, however it still does not solve the main point which is **collapsing** the content instead of **scrolling**. I'm looking for the solution which allows me to keep both `TextView`s on one `RelativeLayout` and during the toolbar being collapsed, layout height is being changed.

Comment: Oh, then it seems like can be achievable by custom CoordinatorBehaviour. I can't provide you with exact solution but take a look at this article posted by Ian Lake https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26. Perhaps it might give you some valuable points.

Comment: i need to shrink a scichart as the appbarlayout is expanded. is this possible?? doesnt seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to close your  Coordinator layout at the end of the Relative Full code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="The text on the top"
            android:textSize="32sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="The text on the bottom"
            android:textSize="32sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: He already close the CoordinatorLayout.. Pls check the edited question now :)